# Getting error "Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'" in vite

Tags: reactjs, node.js, tailwind-css, vite

I just installed vite with `npm create vite@latest react-app -- --template react` . But I am getting error while trying to run `npm run dev` . I didn't have any tailwindCSS . IDK why I am getting this error.

The error is :

```
PS D:\BlockChain\wagmi test\react-app> npm run dev

> react-app@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v5.2.3  ready in 951 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h + enter to show help
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: D:/BlockChain/wagmi test/react-app): [Error] Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- D:\BlockChain\postcss.config.js

(@D:\BlockChain\postcss.config.js)
Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- D:\BlockChain\postcss.config.js

(@D:\BlockChain\postcss.config.js)
    at load (file:///D:/BlockChain/wagmi%20test/react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Bh2jsKCM.js:29047:11)
    at file:///D:/BlockChain/wagmi%20test/react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Bh2jsKCM.js:29072:16
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at plugins (file:///D:/BlockChain/wagmi%20test/react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Bh2jsKCM.js:29071:8)
    at processResult (file:///D:/BlockChain/wagmi%20test/react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Bh2jsKCM.js:29141:14)
    at file:///D:/BlockChain/wagmi%20test/react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Bh2jsKCM.js:29271:14]

Node.js v18.14.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Now I got the problem. I had the project in  `D:\BlockChain\wagmi test\react-app` this location. But I had my previous `postcss.config.js` and `tailwind.config` etc files in my `Blockchain` directory. These were causing the problem. After deleting these I am able to run the project successfully.